# Setting UseMnemonic for ToolstripLabel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, toolstrip

I have a ToolstripLabel for which I want to set UseMnemonic to false. But it doesn't have this property. Is there a way to do this?

I tried casting it to label, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get to it.  The basic flaw is that the Text of the label is rendered with a TextFormatFlags value that's missing the HidePrefix option.  Getting that value changed is not possible, it is buried inside internal code.

A workaround is to use your own renderer and fix the problem by altering the text before it is rendered.  Make that look like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
    }

    private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
        protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Item is ToolStripItem) e.Text = e.Text.Replace("&", "&&");
            base.OnRenderItemText(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This appears to alter the expected render size of the `ToolStripItemLabel` and then it causes clipping issues on neighboring items.